# List View is not scrolling along with the Expandable List View

Tags: android, xml, listview, expandablelistview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:clickable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/exp_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:groupIndicator="@null">
    </ExpandableListView>
            <ListView
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:id="@+id/menuList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have implemented an Expandable ListView along with a List View.But When I scroll my View then  Expandable ListView is scrollable separately and ListView is scrollable separately.The Simple ListView is not scrolled along with the Expandable ListView.I want that my ListView should also scroll along with the Expandable ListView.Here  is my design for the above code.

[image: my design screenshot]

Comment: you can make logic like if parent child size > 0 then show + and  enable parent click so you dont need to take two listview

Comment: please chek this article it may be helpful http://www.technotalkative.com/part-4-playing-with-navigationview/

Comment: @Android Developer-I used the following implementation according to your suggestion but when i expand my expandable listview and scroll it then a + sign appears on one of the below headers(Share,Feedback,Rate Us,More Apps).As i keep expanding and collapsing my list the + sign appears on the differents headers ..

Comment: @Android Developer-
This is my implementation-
`
 if (isExpanded &&  getChildrenCount(groupPosition)>0) {
            ListHeader.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
                    R.drawable.collapse, 0);
        }
        else if(getChildrenCount(groupPosition)>0){
            ListHeader.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
                    R.drawable.expand, 0);
        }`

Comment: @Android Developer-This is my implementation for getChildrenCount()-
` public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        int childCount = 0;
        if (groupPosition < 2) {
            childCount = this.mListDataChild.get(this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }
        return childCount;
    }`